# Why is 5D in hex represented as bytearray(b']')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, ascii

For example if you represent 5D in a bytearray you get `bytearray(b']')`, but I don't understand why.

Is it because of ASCII and if so, how is Python handling all the ASCII Characters?

Comment: 5D hex is 93 decimal, which is the ascii code for `]`. That's how bytearray's display easily printable characters.

Comment: python2 or python3?  The result is different.

Comment: Try `b']' == chr(0x5d)` in each.

Comment: It's because x5d is a ] character in ASCII and an often annoying thing Python does when displaying the contents of a bytearray, If you want all hex use something like `','.join(f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in ba)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood it's all binary, right?

`5d` in hex is just `01011101` in binary. Turns out that `]` in ascii is the same in binary `01011101`. So really you just have `01011101` or in base10 `93` represented in Hex and Ascii.

Comment: So Python is just using Ascii where it can to save memory when you print it?

Comment: Nothing to do with memory as a byte is a byte is a byte. It's just using ascii as the presentation of the byte. It could also just use hex (or binary or decimal or base29), but for whatever reason they decided to use ascii. I believe you can use `.hex()` method of the bytearray to show it as hex if it's your preference.